# count of transactions by the customer in a month

Tags: mysql, sql

Given the following the tables

**User_info:**

- user_id
- Date

**User_trascations:**

- user_id
- Transaction_date
- Purchase_amount
  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0b73b4

calculating 30day active spenders for Jan 2020-01-01, count (customers
who made at least one transaction in last 30days i.e. 2020-01-01 to 2020-01-31).

```
The result table should be as follows:
-------------------------------------------------------------
Date      |   Total_customers |   Customers_who_made_purchase
-------------------------------------------------------------

01-01-2020     100               20
02-01-2020     200               60
Total          300               80
```

How do I get the totals in the last row? that too in SQL?

I have tried this:

```
select
  date(User_info.date) as date 
  , count(distinct User_trascations.user_id), 
      count(distinct User_info.user_id) as conversion
from User_info join User_trascations
  on User_info.user_id = User_trascations.user_id
group by 1
```

Comment: share sample data and its output

Comment: Updated the sample

Comment: With the current sample data you provided, there are no transactions in januari 2020. Also the bit about 'last 30 days' is confusing. Starting from 2020-01-01, the remainder of the month is the 'NEXT 30 days'.

Comment: I don't fully get what you're trying to say, but i guess what you're looking for it's a kind of Sumary Report (Totals) at the end of the results, and this can be done using Rollup or Cube. I'll post a little sample based on your last query attempt (just to give you an idea).

Comment: Always put date fields as a date/time type. Leaving free text data makes it hard to do operations on it.

Comment: Store dates using a date data type, or don't bother with an RDBMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i said in the comments, this is an example to give you an idea about how to get the result you're looking for.

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(A.Date, 'Total') AS User_Date,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(B.User_Id)) AS Total_Customers,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(A.User_Id)) AS Customer_Purchases
FROM
    USER_INFO A JOIN USER_TRASCATIONS B ON
    A.User_Id = B.User_Id
GROUP BY
    ROLLUP(A.Date)
```

The Coalesce function it's like an if/else. When value is null (A.Date value), then it will return the passed string ('Total'). This will be the text you see at the end of the result (the summary).

The Rollup function works with the Group By to define result groups and get the resume at the last row.

Comment: if I am using the following code where cshould I include roll up?

Comment: `SELECT t1.date_t1 AS Date, 
total_users_on_a_day,
Users_who_made_pruchase
FROM 
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT User_ID) total_users_on_a_day,
STR_TO_DATE(`Date`,'%m/%d/%y') date_t1 
FROM daily_active_users
GROUP BY STR_TO_DATE(`Date`,'%m/%d/%y')) t1
 INNER JOIN 
 (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT User_ID) Users_who_made_pruchase,
 DATE(`Date_Time`) date_t2 
 FROM rev 
 GROUP BY DATE(`Date_Time`)with rollup) t2
 ON t1.date_t1 = t2.date_t2 `